# MSXML2.XMLHTTP error for google translate due to CAPTCHA

Tags: excel, google-translate, msxml, vba

I have been using a public function in excel to do basic translating for some time now. In the past week i started recieving "#VALUE!" for the results and i have narrowed it down to the MSXML2.XMLHTTP portion of the code. Here is the function:

```
Public Function Translate(ByVal strText As String, _
                      Optional ByVal eFrom As eLanguage = auto_detect, _
                      Optional ByVal eTo As eLanguage = english, _
                      Optional ByVal blnPhonetic As Boolean = False) As String

Dim strUrl
Dim strTransText As String
Dim strResult As String
Dim varSplitText As Variant
Dim lngItem As Long
Dim delimitChar As String
delimitChar = Chr(34) & "," 'Chr(34) is the character for "


If strText = "" Then
    Translate = ""
    Exit Function
End If

strText = URLEncode(strText)

strUrl = "http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=s&text={S}&hl=en&sl={F}&tl={T}&multires=1&pc=0&rom=1&sc=1"

strUrl = Replace$(strUrl, "{S}", strText)
strUrl = Replace$(strUrl, "{F}", Split(strSHORTCODES, ",")(eFrom))
strUrl = Replace$(strUrl, "{T}", Split(strSHORTCODES, ",")(eTo))



With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Call .Open("get", strUrl, False)
    Call .Send
    strResult = .responseText
End With


varSplitText = Split(Split(strResult, "]],")(0), "[")


If Not blnPhonetic Then
    For lngItem = 3 To UBound(varSplitText)
        strTransText = strTransText & Split(varSplitText(lngItem), delimitChar)(0)
    Next
Else
    For lngItem = 3 To UBound(varSplitText)
        strTransText = strTransText & Split(varSplitText(lngItem), ",")(2)
    Next
End If
strResult = Replace(strTransText, """", "")


Translate = strResult
End Function
```

The problem is happening when the strURL is being sent after:

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Call .Open("get", strUrl, False)
    Call .Send
    strResult = .responseText
End With
```

I have verifired that the strURL is being created correctly and have entered this into the browser with positive results. The only problem i found is that on the first try entering into the browser i was taken into a CAPTCHA page to verify my existance. This is creating an issue when i call the translate function. Is there any way to get around this?

An example of strURL that is created using during execution of the function:
http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=s&text=%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AF&hl=en&sl=&tl=en&multires=1&pc=0&rom=1&sc=1
If you enter this into your browser you will probably get a CAPTCHA response. The this url is just the translation of hello from japanese.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find a way around that CAPTCHA error (which may be difficult, as the task you are attempting to accomplish is the reason CAPTCHAs exist in the first place), you may consider some of the alternatives listed below.

I was looking among alternatives to Google's Translate API (because that costs money, $20 per 1 million characters I believe), and I did find that Microsoft offers a free 2 million characters / month option.  I found several other paid options as well from a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api) and some quick independent research.

Free:

- [Microsoft Translate](http://www.microsoft.com/translator/get-started.aspx) (free for 2 million characters / month)
- [Yandex](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate-docpage/) (must sign up for API key, but usage appears to be completely free)
- [Hablaa](http://hablaa.com/api/) (free, no registration)

Paid

- [Gengo API](http://gengo.com/pricing-languages/) (paid, $0.05 / word)
- [SpeakLike](http://www.speaklike.com/plans/) (paid, $0.05 / word or pre-paid bulk packages)

The website [ProgrammableWeb has 60+ results for translation APIs](http://www.programmableweb.com/category/translation/apis?category=20254) of which you (hopefully) can find something that suits your needs.

Of everything listed, Microsoft Translate seems to be the winner, if you want it to be free.  You know the name, it is well documented, reliable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is the actual site translate tool, which isn't the proper way to use the translate api - Take a look at the proper REST API:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/